# IIS 7.5 - Windows 2008R2 App pools - Compare

Tags: iis-7.5, 64-bit

I'm troubleshooting a scenario where the same ASP.Net MVC web application hosted in 2 different application pools (in the same server) having very different memory footprints.

One app pool (say pool 'A') is having default values from IIS while the other (say pool 'B') has been tampered with. By using the IIS Management console, I've made sure that 'B' is having exactly similar settings to 'A'. However I still see the memory footprint of 'B' going well over 650 MB before stabilizing while 'A' stabilizes around 350 MB (Under the same load)

What I want to know is whether there's any other mechanism (beside using IIS mgmt console) to compare and contrast app pool settings.

Any other advice on how I'm troubleshooting this is also appreciated.

Uchitha.

Comment: After doing some memory profiling with ANTS memory profiler 8 - I figured out that the majority of the memory allocated for the app pool is taken up by 'Unused memory allocated to .Net' category. My Gen1, Gen2 and Large Object Heap (LOH) together take around 30MB on average. Is this normal behaviour?